# Unity 3d - List<> ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: unity3d

Добрый день друзья!
Есть небольшая проблема в Unity 3D (4.6.1f1), а именно вылетает ошибка следующего содержания:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: index
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UnityEngine.UILineInfo].get_Item (Int32 index) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:633)
UnityEngine.UI.InputField.SetDrawRangeToContainCaretPosition (UnityEngine.TextGenerator gen, Int32 caretPos, System.Int32& drawStart, System.Int32& drawEnd) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/UI/Core/InputField.cs:1405)
UnityEngine.UI.InputField.UpdateLabel () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/UI/Core/InputField.cs:1347)
UnityEngine.UI.InputField.SendOnValueChangedAndUpdateLabel () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/UI/Core/InputField.cs:1245)
UnityEngine.UI.InputField.set_text (System.String value) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/UI/Core/InputField.cs:275)
toogleClass.getShemaData () (at Assets/scripts/toogleClass.js:274)
toogleClass.showShemaData () (at Assets/scripts/toogleClass.js:169)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:110)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCallList.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:575)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEventBase.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:717)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:53)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/UI/Core/Button.cs:36)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/UI/Core/Button.cs:45)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:52)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/Extensions/guisystem/guisystem/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:269)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

Притом, что в консоле показывает, что длина списка 10, а вылетает эта ошибка иногда даже на i=0:

[image: Screenshot Console]

Причем ошибка не вылазит постоянно, после повторного запуска может не проявится.
Так что прошу помощи у гуру, подскажите, что я делаю не так и куда копать?
Заранее благодарю всех откликнувшихся!

Code js:

```
    var doIt: List.<String> = getDoItByShemaName(transform.parent.name);    
    Debug.Log(doIt.Count);  

    parent = settingScript.shemaData.transform.GetChild(2).GetChild(0);

    if(settingScript.mainScript.lang == 'ru'){

        doingName = settingScript.doingName_ru;

    }else {

        doingName = settingScript.doingName_en;
    }

    if(doIt.Count > 0) { 

        try{

            for( var i: int = 0; i < doingName.Count; i++) {

                shemaDataInst  = Instantiate(settingScript.prefabShemaData);

                dataField = shemaDataInst.GetChild(2).GetComponent.<InputField>();

                doItField = shemaDataInst.GetChild(1).GetComponent.<InputField>();

                doItName = shemaDataInst.GetChild(0).GetComponent.<Text>();

                shemaDataInst.name = settingScript.doItColumeNames[i];                  

                doItName.text = doingName[i];
                Debug.Log(i);
274 строка с ошибкой    doItField.text = doIt[i];
            }


        }catch(e: FormatException){

            Debug.Log(e);
        }
}
```

Comment: Вам не кажется, что в конце кода что-то не хватает? Поправте.

Comment: ну значит у тебя не всегда отрабатывает `getDoItByShemaName(transform.parent.name);` или ничего не возвращает..... в результате чего у тебя иногда `doIt` всё-таки оказывается пуст

Comment: Ребята спасибо за участие!!! Конечно первое , что приходит на ум после такой ошибки это , как раз то что функция не вернула  List, поэтому сразу проверил длину , значение присутствует!  Я просто не знаю как это еще можно проверить

Comment: другой причины быть не может...... и поэтому  я написал `не всегда отрабатывает` .... то есть можешь воспользоваться отладчиком, в котором можно указать в какой момент сработать.... например когда внутри `getDoItByShemaName` будет list.count == 0  и посмотреть почему так происходит и в какой момент

Comment: У меня уже подозрения на то , что это сбой матрицы  ![Console](http://prntscr.com/ezh3xt)   Ошибка появляется в начальных итерациях по массиву, успевает перебрать весь массив и только потом останавливает рендеринг сцены